# Proven approaches for labeling recordings for training a speech-to-text model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, audio-recognition, speech-to-text

To train a deep learning model, for converting speech to text, we need **labeled data**. How should this data be arranged?
I'm interested in building the model from scratch and not using ready-made libraries or models, and I know it's a lot of work.

I can think of several approaches, and I don't know which approach has already been tried in the world, and which has not yet, and which approach was successful and which was less so.

Here are the approaches I thought of:

1. Divide the speech into short and **fixed periods** of time, for example `40 milliseconds`, hoping that each part will catch one letter, then listen to each part and give it the correct label.
   The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to label words but letters, and we have several dozens of letters in ABC and we gave each letter several examples and we were done.
2. Divide the speech into longer, but **fixed periods** of time, for example of `1 second`, in the hope that each part will capture one complete word, then listen to each part and give it the correct label. [It's a lot of work...]
3. Divide the speech into **varying periods** of time, each part will be from `silence to silence`, and what is considered silence will be determined according to what average threshold. Then listen to each part and give it the correct notation. [It's also a lot of work...]

I'm interested to know what approaches have been taken by those who have already succeeded in developing deep learning models.

Comment: 1 and 2 don't work. You need context for any speech or text-related task like this one. Also, you need HUGE amounts of data to train deep learning models, so, in general, it's not a good idea to label your own data if you can get data from somewhere else. You can check STT datasets to check what kind of labelling works.